# How to make a XAML view (a page) inherit from a class, that uses UserControl as generic type

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, inheritance

I have an issue, and I don't know if I can do that, or if there is another way to do that. I have an abstract class called "BasePage", it is my .NET Standard library, so I can't access to System.Windows namespace. Its declaration is:

```
public abstract class BasePage<VR> where VR : new()
```

**EDIT:** The class above has a public property to access to VR

So now, for each platform (WPF, Xamarin, etc) I have to create its own implementation of the class begin **VR** the content control of each platform (UserControl for WPF, for example). I already did it and this is:

```cs
public class WindowsBasePage : BasePage<UserControl>
```

Now, every time I want to create a page to add content to a window, I have to create something like this:

```
 public partial class UserPassPage : WindowsBasePage
 {
     public UserPassPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
 }
```

The problem becomes when I have to set it in the XAML file (the View). I can create it and it builds:

```
<local:WindowsBasePage x:Class="Bitture.AppManager.Manager.UserPassPage"
    [...]
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bitture.AppManager.Manager"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >
</local:WindowsBasePage>
```

but I **can't** add components (like buttons, text, grids, stackpanels, etc). I want to know If I can do it with my current code or there is something I have to change. Because I have to access to the generic type `WindowsBasePage` that inherits from

```
class WindowsBasePage : BasePage<UserControl>
```

Comment: "but I can add components"? What exaclty is your issue here?

Comment: @mm8 Sorry, I will edit it. It says, I can't add components

Comment: Why would you to be able to add controls to a `BasePage<UserControl>`? This is not a `ContentControl` or a `Panel`, is it?

Comment: But BasePage is not a ControlControl?

Comment: No, BasePage is no a content control because it is thought to be cross-platform. But I thought I can use the generic type of BasePage as contentcontrol and make use of it in Xaml @mm8

Comment: Sorry, your approach won't work. How is WPF supposed to know how to render a `BasePage<UserControl>`? How are you intending to use the `UserPassPage` in your application?

Comment: @Tomas when you use MVVM properly you *don't* need to inherit from anything other than a UserControl. You can use composition and data binding to display a nested view model and its corresponding view inside a parent page. For example, you can use ContentControl with a template selector that display whichever View is appropriate for the type you bind it to

Comment: Frameworks like Aurelia or MvvmLight can automate composition by finding and selecting the appropriate view when you bind a ContentControl to a ViewModel.

Comment: I want to make that way because BasePage will have some methods to animate the content and other things

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here but you can't add `UIElements` to a custom class of yours that doesn't inherit from any of the common WPF base classes such as for example `Panel` or `ContentControl`, and expect it to be rendered as a `UserControl` or some other WPF control.

This won't work. WPF knows about how to render WPF controls but it doesn't know how to render a custom `BasePage<UserControl>`.